stxvd2x assembly instruction and vs12 register on Linux ppc64le
Linux 3.10.0-693.el7.ppc64le
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC)
A piece of code compiled with -O3 in the form of
allocate a memory for a structure variable s
s->member1 = 0;
s->member2 = s->member3 = NULL;
s->member4 = s->member5 = NULL;

Note that member2,member3, member4 and member5 are pointers to structures and their order is
member3;
member2;
member4;
member5;

has the assembly as
stxvd2x vs12,r14,r20     >>>> s->member3
stxvd2x vs12,r14,r21     >>>> s->member4
stw     r18,72(r14)      >>>> s->member1

printing the values of "s->member3" and "s->member4" shows that they are both 0x1.
member3 = 0x1, member2 = 0x0, member4 = 0x1, member5 = 0x0

Looking at the value of "vs12" in the debugger shows
(gdb) p $vs12
$31 = {uint128 = 0x00000000000000010000000000000000, 
       v2_double = {0, 4.9406564584124654e-324}, 
       v4_float = {0, 0, 1.40129846e-45, 0}, 
       v4_int32 = {0, 0, 1, 0}, 
       v8_int16 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
       v16_int8 = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

Can anyone explain this 'vs12' register and its values?
